# GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag returning (clone)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, tags, gameobject, animator

im having this problem and its when i use

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("red");
```

it started when i added an animator component to the gameObject

its returning

```
red(Clone)
```

when the game object is in the heirarchy as the only gameobject with the tag "red"
it only happened after i added the animator component and when i exited from unity and restarted unity the problem went away, the error i was getting was

MissingComponentException: There is no 'Rigidbody2D' attached to the "red(Clone)" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

there is a red in the scene not a red(clone) but i seen in the inspector when i used GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("red") it found red(Clone) but there is no red(Clone) just red in the scene, it happened after i added a animator component and stopped when i rebooted Unity, its gota be a bug, just thought id check here

**edit**
just how i said that there was a red in the scene there was a RigidBody2d attached to it too, just no existence of a red(Clone), thank you for your time

Comment: Do you happen to instantiate the game object in question? Or is any instantiation happening ?

Comment: no, not at all, theres only 1 red GameObject thats in the scene already, no instantiating going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a long running bug in unity, dating all the way back to 4.3. Which hopefully will be fixed in unity 5

It seems the animator window causes a clone for some reason, which is not removable.

There are only 2 ways to bypass this problem as known to date

- If you did not save the scene yet, close the animator window, close unity and restart unity. This should rid you of the object.

in case you already saved the scene

- Use another tag instead, so instead of *red* use *Red*.

General advice, try to avoid using the FindGameObjectWithTag as long as the bug is running. As stability is not guaranteed.

Some other less optimal ways to deal with this problem:

- Find and destroy the clones before using it:

  ```
  GameObject[] remaining = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(Tags.player);
  foreach (GameObject clone in remaining) {
  if(clone.name == "Player_Aleysha(Clone)"){
        GameObject.Destroy(clone);
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks, i knew it was a bug, im just concerned that it doesnt happen in the editor and in the actual player, thanks

Comment: @MX D: have you submitted the bug report? Or does someone did? I have that problem too but still haven't been able to reproduce it consistently for a bug report. If you have a repro case, please submit it (or share it and I'll take care of it).

Comment: @Heisenbug Nobody has been able to consistently re-produce the bug. All that is known is that the object is caused by the Animator window, which seems to provide a ghost object that is not always properly removed. As the bug is not consistent, it is not on a high priority fix list. But as of unity 5 there will be new animator features. Which hopefully fixed this bug, or enables us to consistently recreate it.

Comment: @MX D: yes animator windows actually create and go's instance that should be flagged as HideAndDontSave so actually it shouldn't be searchable through FindGameObjectWithTag.. . Still didn't happen in unity 5..so maybe it's been fixed or no more happens for some reasons. btw let me know if you have news on that